# not able to install Java on aws ec2 instance

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am new to Amazon Web Services. I have created one ec2 instance and want to install Java on that. 
I have downloaded rpm file but not able to execute it. below is the list of folder/files under root.

```
root@ip-172-31-6-12:~# ls
install.sh  jdk1.8_1.8.0171-1_amd64.deb  node_modules  node-v8.11.3.tar.gz
jdk-10.0.1  jdk-8u171-linux-x64.rpm      node-v8.11.3  survey
```

and when I am running

```
dpkg -i jdk1.8_1.8.0171-1_amd64.deb
```

I am getting this message.

```
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: warning: 'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 2 expected programs not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
```

please let me know, what I am missing here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try to install java from the distribution packages. Like `apt-get install java-openjdk`.
The other problem seems to be that you've downloaded an rpm and you are trying to install on debian. RPM's are for RHEL/CentOS like distributions.

Comment: while running this command (apt-get install java-openjdk) I am getting these messages:
root@ip-172-31-6-12:~# apt-get install java-openjdk
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Comment: That's strange, you seem to be root already, the correct command should be `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`. Try that.

Comment: Glad to help! @Yashpal